# iOS app in two different languages without localization

Tags: ios, uitableview, localization

I have build an `iOS` app in English language. Now client wants to release it in Arabic also. I don't want to use localization for this purpose. Is there a way we can handle constraints for this purpose? I'm facing more issues when it comes to `UITableView` mirroring for arabic language. Any workaround?

Comment: I think localisation is good option , it will automatically mirroring your all UI for Arabic (right to left).

Comment: make some languageManager and add some different language dictionary class and whenever setting the text just grab the required one

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Right, we can display text for the language but how shall we adjust our views accordingly without changing the constraints much?

Comment: I guess we are writing something mostly on UILabels and they are intrinsic. They will grow and shrink accordingly with the text. Just use minimum UILabel layout contraints. Say for example a UILabel just requires Leading and top constraint and it can set its width accordingly with some text

Comment: Please define what you mean by not using 'localization'–do you mean localizing interface files directly as opposed to strings? You should use as much of the base system API as possible to give you the least amount of headaches. Also please show a screenshot of the issues you're having with UITableView mirroring.

Answer (score -1):

if you not want mirroring your views... then just go in your constraint properties and uncheck option "respect langugage" and then your views remain same in any langaugage